# How to add WFS and WMS in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

I have two service url like WFS and WMS below:

http://neii.bom.gov.au/services/solarclim/wms/data/monClim_dirNorExp1Hou.nc?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=topp:states&TILED=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&BBOX=45%2c-67.5%2c56.25%2c-56.25

http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/datavic/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=datavic:VMADMIN_LGA_POLYGON&SRSNAME=EPSG:4283&cql_filter=LGA_CODE=325

I want those two services need to add as layer in my openlayers map. Is it possible and how?

**Updated code with sample data:**

```
myFunction(layerUrl:string, layer: any) {
        var bbox = layer.BoundingBox[0].extent;
        var crs = layer.BoundingBox[0].crs;

        var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: `${layerUrl}`,
            params: {'LAYERS': `${layer.Name}`, 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            projection: `${crs}`,
            // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
            transition: 0
        });

        var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            extent: bbox,
            source: wmsSource
        });

        map.addLayer(wmsLayer);

        map.getView().fit(wmsLayer.getExtent());
    }
```

Layer url here: 
https://wms.geo.admin.ch/

Here is layer object:

```
Abstract: "Als Kulturgüter von nationaler Bedeutung im Inventar von 2009 gelten rund 3200 Objekte (Einzelbauten / Sammlungen in Museeen, Archiven und Bibliotheken sowie Archäologie)."
Attribution: {Title: "Das Geoportal des Bundes", OnlineResource: "http://www.geo.admin.ch/", LogoURL: {…}}
BoundingBox: [{…}]
CRS: (14) ["epsg:2056", "epsg:21781", "epsg:4326", "epsg:3857", "epsg:3034", "epsg:3035", "epsg:4258", "epsg:31287", "epsg:25832", "epsg:25833", "epsg:31467", "epsg:32632", "epsg:32633", "epsg:900913"]
Dimension: undefined
EX_GeographicBoundingBox: (4) [0.659965, 45.4183, 10.8344, 48.7495]
Layer: (2) [{…}, {…}]
MaxScaleDenominator: undefined
MinScaleDenominator: undefined
Name: "ch.babs.kulturgueter"
Style: [{…}]
Title: "KGS Inventar"
cascaded: undefined
fixedHeight: undefined
fixedWidth: undefined
noSubsets: false
opaque: false
queryable: false
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: See this example 
FOR WMS http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html
FOR WFS http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html

Comment: Try using that example if you found any problem show us what you did we will help you

Comment: @Atanu in your given wms example extent is hard code, how to use dynamic one?

Comment: See this example also http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-no-proj.html

Comment: Hi @Atanu thanks for your quick reply. From this service url https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms I am getting list of layers and now I want to show some layers from the list not all. Suppose that one layer, can you provide some sample code by which I can add that specific layer into openlayers map?

Comment: Sorry i don't have any ready example right now, perhaps if you provide your code i can help you with that

Comment: @Atanu I have updated my post with code and sample data. I can't see any result when executes the code. It is focusing on the map but no layer added there. Could you please review the code and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Atanu could you please check my code and reply on it, so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late reply, but i use this code in my project with custom settings and this provide me a valid output.
Code is as follows [ please change static ip with your variable ]

```
var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
     url: 'https://wms.geo.admin.ch/',
     params: {'LAYERS': 'ch.babs.kulturgueter','TILED': true},
     serverType: 'geoserver',
     projection: 'EPSG:4326',
     transition: 0
});

var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: wmsSource
});

map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

And the output is as follows: [ working just fine ]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Atanu, can I use your code for wfs service also? I think wms and wfs same thing, right?

Comment: @user10496245 wfs is basically  Vector Layer source, Not an WMS title, See this example http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html

Comment: they used the url as example is confusing to me: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
              'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'

Comment: I have seen some wfs sample url like: http://gisserver.domain.com:6080/arcgis/services/wfs_services/enterprise_wfs/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: in this last sample url they didn't use bbox or projection , so in this case their code will not work I think, can you help me on this issue?

Comment: see your WFS url, the outputFormat is **application/json** . follow this link to know more about WFS request 
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

Comment: @ Atanu I want to get all featurelisttype from wfs service but readFeatures method of wfs in openlayers doesn't work, can you give me some sample of such tasks?

Comment: this sample is for single layer how about when we have more than one layers, my mean is I should iterate addLayer or add new ol. source. TileWMS to wmssource with for loop?